# Reloading a Subview Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have this code which sets the a subview to the view of a certain ViewController based on which option is selected in a table view. Here is the code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self setMainView:[[[self controllerArray] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] view]];
    [self setCurrentViewController:[indexPath row]];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

The code which originally adds the subview looks like this:

```
[self setMainView:[[[self controllerArray] objectAtIndex:0] view]];
[[self view] addSubview:[self mainView]]
```

The problem is that the code that changes the subview does not update the subview so the view never actually loads. I can reload the view by removing it from the subview (`[[self mainView] removeFromSuperview]`), but this causes it to load back in the center. The subview can move depending on user gestures and I would like to keep it in the same place. Is there a way to reload the subview or do I have to keep track of where the subview is and then set it after removing it and adding it again.

**EDIT:**
An interesting note:
This code works perfectly (view stays at previous coordinate):

```
[[self mainView] removeFromSuperview];
[self setMainView:[[[self controllerArray] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] view]];
[[self view] addSubview:[self mainView]];
[self setCurrentViewController:[indexPath row]];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Except for the first time the view is switched. I could set the coordinates once, but is there a faster way, so I don't have to remove and add the view every time I want it switched.

Comment: What do you mean by "reload"?

Comment: You should implement `layoutSubviews` method on your view controller's view and call `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` to readjust the position of all of your subviews.

Comment: @JustinMeiners The view does not automatically update to the new view (it still shows the old view after I set it to the new one). Is there a way to update it.

Comment: @Eimantas Setting the position is not the problem. The Problem is reloading content.

Comment: @cabellicar123 so you remove a view? add a new view? and it still shows the old view?

Comment: @JustinMeiners No. Removing the view and adding it again works, but I was wondering if there is a way to reload the content in order to save time and code.

Comment: @cabellicar123 there is a replaceSubview method.. Wait is this the same view you remove and then add again? Or different.

Comment: @JustinMeiners The mainView property is what is added as the sub view. It is then changed. I will try replace sub view.

Comment: @JustinMeiners I do not see a method called replaceSubview

Answer (score 0):

Does this fix the problem?

```
[[self mainView] removeFromSuperview];
[self setMainView:[[[self controllerArray] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] view]];
[self addSubview:[self mainView]];
[self setCurrentViewController:[indexPath row]];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

EDIT1:
If it's just the position that you want to reset, you can add a property CGRect originalFrame and in the code where you added subview add:

```
[self setMainView:[[[self controllerArray] objectAtIndex:0] view]];
[[self view] addSubview:[self mainView]];
self.originalFrame = [self mainView].frame;
```

and then when you want to reset the position use:

```
[[self mainView] setFrame:self.originalFrame];
```

EDIT2:
Maybe it would be enough to use the "hidden" property of the views? That way you could keep them all as subviews at once, but make only one visible, like this

```
[self mainView].hidden = YES;
[self setMainView:[[[self controllerArray] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] view]];
[self mainView].hidden = NO;
[self setCurrentViewController:[indexPath row]];
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

Remember to add all the subviews at start, and set hidden on them to YES, except for the view you want to be visible first.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but as stated in the question, I know I can do this, but I would like a faster method and one with less code (I would have to reset the coordinates of the view)

Comment: Edited the answer. Is this what you needed?

Comment: Again, thanks for the try, but I know how to set the position. I am wondering for solution which is less time consuming (it takes a little while to remove and add the subview)

Comment: Then it seems I don't quite understand what do you want to do. Can you explain step by step what is your goal?

Comment: I have the ability to make this work: see the edit. I am now wondering what if there is a better way to update the subview so that I do not have to remove it and then add it again.

Comment: Sooo... you want a faster way of switching subviews than using removeFromSuperview on old one and using addSubview on new one?

Comment: Can you explain step by step what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes. I would like to do that.

Comment: Edited the answer. Is this what you needed?

Comment: Does the hidden function keep the views in the background because that might slow down the app.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33360/discussion-between-cabellicar123-and-johnyu)